# google maps api 3 route finder (distance of POI from route)

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have the following code which is successfully plotting a route between two points. However I wish to search a recordset to see which georeferences lie within a range of this route. E.g. 50 yards off the main route

```
function plot_route() {

         var rendererOptions = { map: map };
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);

    var org = new google.maps.LatLng ( $("#start_lat").html(), $("#start_long").html() );
    var dest = new google.maps.LatLng ( $("#finish_lat").html(), $("#finish_long").html() );

        if ($("#via_lat").html() != "") {
       var point1 = new google.maps.LatLng($("#via_lat").html(), $("#via_long").html());
        }
        else
        {
         point1 = dest;
        }

    var wps = [{ location: point1 }];

    if (($("#start_lat").html() != "") && ($("#finish_lat").html() != "")) {
    var request = {
            origin: org,
            destination: dest,
            waypoints: wps,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
            };

    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                }
                else
                    alert ('failed to get directions');
            });
    }
}
```

I have tried breaking down the response but it shows that the calculation does not return an array of values to make up the route.

Has anyone conquered this one before?

edit

Digging Deeper, it seems the response does contain the array of route points. For those in the community who are looking for help rather than contributions from people gung ho with the -1 button i attach the following

```
function plot_route() {

         var rendererOptions = { map: map };
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);

    var org = new google.maps.LatLng ( $("#start_lat").html(), $("#start_long").html() );
    var dest = new google.maps.LatLng ( $("#finish_lat").html(), $("#finish_long").html() );

        if ($("#via_lat").html() != "") {
       var point1 = new google.maps.LatLng($("#via_lat").html(), $("#via_long").html());
        }
        else
        {
         point1 = dest;
        }

    var wps = [{ location: point1 }];

    if (($("#start_lat").html() != "") && ($("#finish_lat").html() != "")) {
    var request = {
            origin: org,
            destination: dest,
            waypoints: wps,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
            };

    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                                   var myroute = response.routes[0];
                                   if(myroute)
                                   {
                                       $.each(myroute, function(key, value) {
                                       if (key == "overview_path") {
                                          alert(value); //the array of points for the route
                                       }
                                     });
                                    }
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                }
                else
                    alert ('failed to get directions');
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but from your edit, it looks like you may have answered your own question? Do you need help with looking up the nearby point-of-interest locations or do you already have that covered?

Comment: Thanks Sean, I have that covered. Im posting the response from google to some ajax to get my eventual results

Comment: Ok, it looked like you were good. Also, it's [ok to answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16930/185112). It lets others know that the question has been answered and that they can find good information by reviewing your question.